# Matplotlib: get_xticks() gives wrong result after using ax.set_aspect()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a scatter plot, then using `ax.set_aspect('equal')` (which changes the number and locations of the ticks on the x-axis), and then I try to access the locations of the ticks with `ax.get_xticks()`. However, this gives me the old locations of the ticks, before `set_aspect` resized the axes. See the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(x, 2*x)
print(ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_aspect('equal')
print(ax.get_xticks())
```

This outputs:

```
[-2.  0.  2.  4.  6.  8. 10.]
[-2.  0.  2.  4.  6.  8. 10.]
```

which shows the result does not change.

The code generates the following plot, which shows the x-ticks definitely have changed:
[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpGYM.png)

How do I access the new locations of the x-ticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect ratio isn't applied until draw time for reasons of efficiency.  You can do:

```py
print(ax.get_xticks())
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.apply_aspect()
print(ax.get_xticks())
```

and you will get the new ticks.

Comment: That works, but I do find it strange that using `ax.set_aspect('equal')` does not immediately update the tick locations, but `fig.set_size_inches()` or `fig.subplots_adjust()` does.

Comment: I agree with you - there are many inconsistencies with how axes are updated in Matplotlib.  You could open an issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues